# bash store output of command in array

Tags: arrays, bash, counting

I'm trying to find if the output of the following command, stores just one file in the array array_a

```
array_a = $(find /path/dir1 -maxdepth 1 -name file_orders?.csv)
echo $array_a
/path/dir1/file_orders1.csv /path/dir1/file_orders2.csv
echo ${#array_a[@]}
1
```

So it tell's me there's just one element, but obviously there are 2.
If I type echo ${array_a[0]} it doesn't return me anything. It's like, the variable array_a isn't an array at all. How can i force it to store the elements in array?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lacking the parentheses which define an array. But the fundamental problem is that running `find` inside backticks will split on whitespace, so if any matching file could contain a space, it will produce more than one element in the resulting array.

With `-maxdepth 1` anyway, just use the shell's globbing facilities instead; you don't need `find` at all.

```
 array_a=(/path/dir1/file_orders?.csv)
```

Also pay attention to quotes when using the array.

```
 echo "${array_a[@]}"
```

Without the quotes, the whitespace splitting will happen *again*.